# ColdFusion query four days ago

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I want to query order information from 4 days ago. I cannot quite get the query to use the full 24hours of the day though:

```
<cfquery name="rsByDate" datasource="#request.dsn#">
    SELECT tbl_customers.cst_FirstName
            , tbl_customers.cst_LastName
            , tbl_customers.cst_Email
            , tbl_orders.order_ID
            , tbl_orders.order_Date
    FROM  tbl_customers INNER JOIN tbl_orders 
               ON tbl_customers.cst_ID = tbl_orders.order_CustomerID
    WHERE tbl_orders.order_Date >= #CreateODBCDateTime(DateAdd("d",-5,Now()))#
    AND   tbl_orders.order_Date <= #CreateODBCDateTime(DateAdd("d",-4,Now()))#
    AND   order_Status = 3
    ORDER BY tbl_orders.order_Date DESC
</cfquery>
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to perform this query and then use `cfmail` to ask the customers to review us four days after their order is marked as status 3 'shipped'.

I think I have the date settings not quite right. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're basing your filter dates on `now()`, which has a time component.  So `now()-4` for me is 5/11/2012, but at 12:10pm.  You only want to use the date part for the filter.

You should never hard-code your dynamic values in your SQL string anyhow, so firstly use `<cfqueryparam>` to parameterise your dynamic values, and then use a `CF_SQL_DATE` as the type, which *should* only pass the date through, not the date/time.  I am not in a position to test this for you at the moment, but try that... if it still passes the time part of the date/time, then create a date object with just the date part, using `createDate()`.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the reply.

so is this what you had in mind?

<cfquery name="rsByDate" datasource="#request.dsn#" username="#request.dsnUsername#" password="#request.dsnPassword#">
SELECT tbl_customers.cst_FirstName, tbl_customers.cst_LastName, tbl_customers.cst_Email, 
tbl_orders.order_ID, tbl_orders.order_Date
FROM tbl_customers 
INNER JOIN tbl_orders ON tbl_customers.cst_ID = tbl_orders.order_CustomerID
WHERE tbl_orders.order_Date = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='CF_SQL_DATE' value='#CreateODBCDate(DateAdd("d",-4,Now()))#'>
AND order_Status = 3
ORDER BY tbl_orders.order_Date DESC
</cfquery>

Comment: Right... so reading on from where I said ".. if it still passes the time part of the date/time...", it goes on to say "then create a date object with just the date part, using createDate()".

Comment: @user1812107 It is hard to tell from the comment but it looks like you removed the **AND** portion of your date logic.  Your example will only match on exact dates.  I think you still need to query for dates between as you were before.

Comment: My understanding was that once we had a date we could search that date in a = statement. I forgot to add from and to dates. Once I had done that it replied with my customers. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that.  S/O sux slightly in that it doesn't allow formatting (even line breaks!) in its comments.

Comment: (Edit to fix typo) Minor correction. By using `<=` you are technically including an extra minute in the comparison ie 11/5/2012 at midnight. It may not make a difference in your case, but ... if you want only the orders *dated* on 11/4/2012 you should use: 
`WHERE Order_Date >= <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', -5, now())#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
AND   Order_Date < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', -4, now())#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> ... `